# I have problem to connect oracle DB with SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleclient, oracle-sqldeveloper

I try connect to my oracle db with oracle SQL developer and received that message:
[pic](http://ioj.com/v/camkp) (pictures 1 and 2)

if i try connect with sql plus, all well.

```
command : select userenv('LANGUAGE') from dual;
result:
Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
SQL> select userenv('LANGUAGE') from dual;

*USERENV('LANGUAGE')
----------------------------------------------------
RUSSIAN_RUSSIA.CL8MSWIN1251*
```

in SQL DEVELOPER: 
(picture 3)

> check\uncheck "Skip NLS Settings", nothing changed.

what the issue is?

Comment: Defect to the US, the programmer's paradise where all texts are in ASCII! ;) Just kidding, it's a NLS problem but I don't know enough to help you fix it, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before in an installation with Oracle 10g on AIX. The problem was that NLS files weren't accessible due to wrong file protection.

The problem is most likely not with SQL Developer but on the server side. When you log in, the server will always try to set regional settings that match the one on your client. That's when the error occurs because the required files aren't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already I think it might be worth asking this question in the [OTN SQL Developer Forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you installed the Western European edition instead of the Universal.  If that's not the case, post the file list from the nls/data directory.